# Java 1.8.0_60, MariaDB v10.0 and , mariadb-java-client 1.2.2, "No suitable driver found"

Tags: java, mysql, driver, mariadb, connector

I'm trying to find out why I cannot connect to mariadb on my laptop.  MariaDB is installed with several databases and I can connect using HeidiSQL without problem.

I'm trying to get a Java application connecting to the database, but I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I have downloaded "mariadb-java-client-1.2.2.jar" and added this to the project.

My database URI is:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
```

I've tried changing the using:

```
jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mysql
```

With the same results.  I've got this working before on another PC, but I don't know why its not working on the laptop?  The user name and password are correct and the same as used to connect with HeidiSQL.

I've tried with both:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

and

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

to register the library and then I read that these aren't required....what am I missing?

Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class clsDB {
//The name of this class    
    private static final String TAG = clsDB.class.toString();   
//Define database URL, user name and password
    private static final String SERVER_ADDR = "localhost";
//The database address on Windows development system    
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mariadb://" + SERVER_ADDR +  ":3306/mysql";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "RRCmcs2014";
//Database connection object    
    private Connection m_con = null;
/**
 * Class constructor    
 * @throws Exception 
 */
    public clsDB() throws Exception {
//Create connection to database     
        connect();
    }
/**
 * @param strMethod the method the error occurs in
 * @param strMsg the message to display
 */
    private void errorMsg(String strMethod, String strMsg) {
        System.out.println(TAG + "." + strMethod + ": " + strMsg);
    }
/**
 * Destructor
 */
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        close();
    }
/**
 * Attempts to close database connection    
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        if ( m_con != null && m_con.isClosed() == false ) {
            m_con.close();
        }       
    }
/**
 * Commits any changes to the database  
 * @throws SQLException
 */
    public void commit() throws SQLException {
        if ( m_con != null && m_con.isClosed() == false ) {
            m_con.commit();
        }
    }
/**
 * Attempts to connect to database  
 * @throws Exception 
 */
    private void connect() throws Exception {
//Get a connection to the database
        m_con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,     
                                                        USER_NAME, 
                                                        PASSWORD);
        if ( m_con == null ) {
            throw new Exception( "Cannot connect to database!" );
        }
//Disable auto-commit       
        m_con.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
/**
 * Performs SQL execute or update   
 * @param strSQL, the SQL statement to perform
 * @return If an insert was performed then the insert ID, 
 *         If an update then the number of effected rows
 */
    public long execute(String strSQL) throws SQLException {
        Statement st = null;
        long lngRC = 0;
        try{
            if ( m_con != null ) {
                if ( m_con.isClosed() == true ) {
                    try{
                        connect();
                    } catch( Exception ex ) {
                        errorMsg("query", ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                st = (Statement)m_con.createStatement();

                if ( (lngRC = (int)st.executeUpdate(strSQL,    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) > 0 ) {
                    if ( strSQL.toUpperCase().startsWith("INSERT") == true ) {
                        ResultSet keys = st.getGeneratedKeys();

                        if ( keys != null ) {
                            keys.next();
                            lngRC = keys.getLong(1);
                        }
                    }                   
                    m_con.commit();
                }
            }
        } catch( SQLException ex ) {
            errorMsg("execute", ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if ( st != null ) {
                st.close();
            }
        }
        return lngRC;
    }       
/**
 * @return The database connection object
 */
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return m_con;
    }
/**
 * Performs SQL query   
 * @param strSQL, the SQL statement to perform
 * @return the result of the query
 */
    public ResultSet query(String strSQL) throws SQLException {
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            if ( m_con != null ) {
                if ( m_con.isClosed() == true ) {
                    try{
                        connect();
                    } catch( Exception ex ) {
                        errorMsg("query", ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                st = (Statement)m_con.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery(strSQL);
            }
        } catch( SQLException ex ) {
            errorMsg("query", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return rs;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you added the mariadb jar to your classpath?

Comment: Yes, the class is both in the folder: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib" and the project folder.

Comment: Neither of those are the classpath. You have to add it to the classpath, which means in an IDE you are supposed to add it using the project preferences, and if you're running from command line, to the `-cp` argument or `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, In my project, "Java Build Path", I have the mariadb-java-client-1.2.2.jar" which is in the project folder, this is visible in the Libraries tab.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: Check that it is in the classpath in the run configuration.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, in the "Run Configurations", "Classpath" tab, I have a User Entries which includes the default classpath, that also has the "mariadb-java-client-1.2.2.jar" listed.  Still no joy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the Mariadb driver 1.2.2 has a hidden dependency on `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`.

You can actually see this if you use the command

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

and look at the resulting stack trace. That command is not necessary for JDBC 4 and above, but it is useful for tracking the reason for failed auto-registration of JDBC drivers.

So, the stack trace you get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:71)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at testing.clsDB.connect(clsDB.java:65)
    at testing.clsDB.<init>(clsDB.java:26)
    at testing.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

This is a bug and it should be reported to the vendors of MariaDB, as they do not mention this requirement/dependency in their [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/).

**Workaround**

For now, your solution is simply to download the [MariaDB driver 1.2.0](https://code.mariadb.com/connectors/java/connector-java-1.2.0/).